# Cómo preservar los datos en un array después darle al submit de otro formulario

Tags: php, json, formularios

Siento que la pregunta sea algo confusa.

La explicación es la siguiente: estoy en proceso de aprender PHP y la profesora nos ha puesto un ejercicio algo complicado (por decirlo de alguna forma), el ejercicio consiste en guardar información recogida de un formulario (varias, de hecho), como en un array, y luego poder modificarla sin eliminar los demás datos del array.

Parece fácil, pero lo malo del tema es que no podemos usar ni sesiones, ni bases de datos, ni ficheros, ni el localstorage. La cosa es que por poder se puede hacer, al menos la profesora nos lo mostró, pero no entendí nada su explicación y, más o menos, he conseguido hacer algo por mí mismo.

Ella nos dijo que el truco estaba en usar json_encode() para pasar los datos en un input hidden, hasta ahí todo ok, he conseguido que el formulario de añadir usuarios guarde más de un usuario mientras que el DNI no esté ya dentro del array, pero el problema está en que estoy haciéndolo todo en una página, porque es la mejor forma de conservar los datos que he encontrado, y en la parte en la que debemos actualizar los datos es donde todo se complica.
Para actualizar los datos lo primero que hago es pedirle el DNI de la persona a modificar con un select/option, pero cuando le doy a enviar me borra los datos de los usuarios que había añadido en la variable $agenda.

Estoy seguro de que el problema está con el isset(), pero llevo una semana con este ejercicio y ya no se me ocurre nada nuevo.

Dejo aquí el código del index.php:

```
<?php
require_once './controllers/modules.php';

if(!isset($_POST['hiddenInputUpdate'])) {
    $newAgenda = [];
} else {
    $newAgenda = decodeData();
    updateData($newAgenda);
}

if(!isset($_POST['hiddenInputReg'])) {
    $agenda = [];
} else {
    $agenda = decodeData();
    addData($agenda);
}

print('<pre>'.print_r($agenda, true).'</pre>');

?>
    <div class="container-panel">
        <main>
            <div id="add-contact" class="section-content">
                <div class="top">
                    <div class="left">
                        <h1>Añadir contactos</h1>
                        <div class="date">
                            <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <div class="theme-toggler">
                            <span class="material-icons-sharp active">light_mode</span>
                            <span class="material-icons-sharp">dark_mode</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <form action='' method="POST" class="w-75 form-register" id="regForm">
                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="regNid" required/>
                            <label for="regNid">DNI</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="regName" required/>
                            <label for="regName">Nombre</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="regSurname" required/>
                            <label for="regSurname">Apellidos</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="regEmail" required/>
                            <label for="regEmail">Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="regTel" required/>
                            <label for="regTel">Teléfono</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="regBirth" required/>
                            <label for="regBirth">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenInputReg" value='<?php echo encodeData($agenda); ?>'>
                            <button type="submit" name="regSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg gradient-custom-4 text-body">Registrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="update-contact" class="section-content">
                <div class="top">
                    <div class="left">
                        <h1>Actualizar contactos</h1>
                        <div class="date">
                            <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <div class="theme-toggler">
                            <span class="material-icons-sharp active">light_mode</span>
                            <span class="material-icons-sharp">dark_mode</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <form class="w-25 my-5" action="" method="POST" id="getNidForm">
                        <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example" name="getNid">
                            <?php
                            if(isset($agenda)){
                                echo '
                                    <option value="noSel" selected>Selecciona un DNI</option>
                                ';
                                foreach($agenda as $key => $value) {
                                    echo '
                                        <option value='.$key.'>'.$key.'</option>
                                    ';
                                }
                            } else {
                                echo '
                                    <option value="noSel" selected>No hay DNIs</option>
                                ';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <button type="submit" name="getNidSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg gradient-custom-4 text-body">Seleccionar</button>
                    </form>
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['getNid']) && !empty($_POST['getNid'])) {
                        if($_POST['getNid'] !== 'noSel') {
                            echo '
                            <form class="my-5" action="" method="POST" id="updForm">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <h2 class="heading">Registrar</h2>
                                    <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="updateNid" value="'.$_POST['getNid'].'">
                                        <label for="updateNid">DNI</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="updateName">
                                        <label for="updateName">Nombre</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="updateSurname">
                                        <label for="updateSurname">Apellidos</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="updateEmail">
                                        <label for="updateEmail">Email</label>
                                    </div>       
                                    <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                                        <input type="tel" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="updatePhone">
                                        <label for="updatePhone">Phone</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="updateBirth"/>
                                        <label for="updateBirth">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-4" style="width: 22rem;">
                                        <label for="registerPic">Selecciona una foto<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                        <input type="file" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="updateFile" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="grid">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="sub-update" value="update">Actualizar</button>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenInputUpdate" value='.encodeData($newAgenda).'>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            ';
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
```

Este fichero es el modules.php:

```
<?php

function getLocalTime() {
    date_default_timezone_set('Atlantic/Canary');
    return date("d-m-Y H:i:s a");
}

function encodeData($data) {
    return json_encode($data);
}

function decodeData() {
    return json_decode($_POST['hiddenInputReg'], true);
}

function cleanData($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

function addData(&$data) {
    $date = getLocalTime();
    if(!in_array($_POST['regNid'], $data) || empty($data)) {
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['nombre'] = cleanData($_POST['regName']);
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['apellidos'] = cleanData($_POST['regSurname']);
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['correo'] = cleanData($_POST['regEmail']);
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['telefono'] = cleanData($_POST['regTel']);
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['fechaNacimiento'] = cleanData($_POST['regBirth']);
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['fechaInsercion'] = $date;
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['bloqueado'] = false;
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['ficheros'] = [];
        return;
    }
    return;
}

function updateData(&$data) {
    if(!in_array($_POST['regNid'], $data) || empty($data)) {
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['nombre'] = cleanData($_POST['regName']);
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['apellidos'] = cleanData($_POST['regSurname']);
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['correo'] = cleanData($_POST['regEmail']);
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['telefono'] = cleanData($_POST['regTel']);
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['fechaNacimiento'] = cleanData($_POST['regBirth']);
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['ficheros'] = $_FILES['updateFile']['name'];
        return;
    }
    return;
}

?>
```

Para resumir, lo que quiero lograr es conservar los datos añadidos con el #regForm incluso si le doy a enviar en el #getNidForm o el #updForm.

Comment: Tal vez leyendo la documentación sobre los tipos de datos y sus funciones te ayude a entender, comprender y poder resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final era tan simple como pasar los datos en cada formulario con el mismo input hidden del registro; también habría que cambiar las condiciones (los isset()) teniendo en cuenta el botón de envío, para diferenciar entre la función addData y updateData.

Por si alguien tiene el mismo problema y se encuentra en algún momento en la misma situación con los mismos vetos que yo, dejo por aquí el código final:

```
if(!isset($_POST['hiddenInputReg'])) {
    $agenda = [];
} else {
    $agenda = decodeData();
    if(isset($_POST['regSubmit'])) {
        addData($agenda);
    } 
    else if(isset($_POST['updSubmit'])) {
        updateData($agenda);
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['blockSubmit'])) {
        setBlock($agenda);
    }
}

print('<pre>'.print_r($agenda, true).'</pre>');

?>
    <div class="container-panel">
        <main>
            <div id="add-contact" class="section-content">
                <div class="top">
                    <div class="left">
                        <h1>Añadir contactos</h1>
                        <div class="date">
                            <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <div class="theme-toggler">
                            <span class="material-icons-sharp active">light_mode</span>
                            <span class="material-icons-sharp">dark_mode</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <form action='' method="POST" class="w-75 form-register" id="regForm">
                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="regNid" required/>
                            <label for="regNid">DNI</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="regName" required/>
                            <label for="regName">Nombre</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="regSurname" required/>
                            <label for="regSurname">Apellidos</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="regEmail" required/>
                            <label for="regEmail">Email</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="regTel" required/>
                            <label for="regTel">Teléfono</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="regBirth" required/>
                            <label for="regBirth">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenInputReg" value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars(encodeData($agenda)); ?>'>
                            <button type="submit" name="regSubmit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg gradient-custom-4 text-body custom-btn">Registrar</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="update-contact" class="section-content">
                <div class="top">
                    <div class="left">
                        <h1>Actualizar contactos</h1>
                        <div class="date">
                            <input type="date" name="date" id="date">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <div class="theme-toggler">
                            <span class="material-icons-sharp active">light_mode</span>
                            <span class="material-icons-sharp">dark_mode</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <form class="w-25 my-5" action="" method="POST" id="getNidForm">
                        <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example" name="getNid">
                            <?php
                            if(isset($agenda)){
                                echo '
                                    <option value="noSel" selected disabled>Selecciona un DNI</option>
                                ';
                                foreach($agenda as $key => $value) {
                                    echo '
                                        <option value='.$key.'>'.$key.'</option>
                                    ';
                                }
                            } else {
                                echo '
                                    <option value="noSel" selected disabled>No hay DNIs</option>
                                ';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <input type="hidden" name="hiddenInputReg" value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars(encodeData($agenda)); ?>'>
                        <button type="submit" name="getNidSubmit" class="btn btn-block btn-lg gradient-custom-4 text-body custom-btn">Seleccionar</button>
                    </form>
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_POST['getNid'])) {
                        foreach($agenda as $key => $val) {
                            if($_POST['getNid'] === $key) {
                                echo '
                                <form class="my-5" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="updForm">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <h2 class="heading">Registrar</h2>
                                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="updateNid" value="'.$key.'">
                                            <label for="updateNid">DNI</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="updateName" value="'.$agenda[$key]['nombre'].'">
                                            <label for="updateName">Nombre</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="updateSurname" value="'.$agenda[$key]['apellidos'].'">
                                            <label for="updateSurname">Apellidos</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                                            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="updateEmail" value="'.$agenda[$key]['correo'].'">
                                            <label for="updateEmail">Email</label>
                                        </div>       
                                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                                            <input type="tel" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="updatePhone" value="'.$agenda[$key]['telefono'].'">
                                            <label for="updatePhone">Phone</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-floating mb-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="updateBirth" value="'.$agenda[$key]['fechaNacimiento'].'">
                                            <label for="updateBirth">Fecha de nacimiento</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="mb-4" style="width: 22rem;">
                                            <label for="updateFile">Selecciona una foto<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                                            <input type="file" class="form-control form-control-lg" name="updateFile"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="grid">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenInputReg" value="'.htmlspecialchars(encodeData($agenda)).'">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn custom-btn" name="updSubmit" value="update">Actualizar</button>
                                        </div>  
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                ';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
```

Aquí está el modules.php donde tengo las demás funciones:

```
<?php

function getLocalTime($mode) {
    date_default_timezone_set('Atlantic/Canary');
    if($mode === 'datetime') {
        return date("d-m-Y H:i:s a");
    }
    return date("d/m/Y");
}

function encodeData($data) {
    return json_encode($data);
}

function decodeData() {
    return json_decode($_POST['hiddenInputReg'], true);
}

function cleanData($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    // $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

function addData(&$data) {
    $date = getLocalTime('datetime');
    if(!in_array($_POST['regNid'], $data) || empty($data)) {
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['nombre'] = cleanData($_POST['regName']);
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['apellidos'] = cleanData($_POST['regSurname']);
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['correo'] = cleanData($_POST['regEmail']);
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['telefono'] = cleanData($_POST['regTel']);
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['fechaNacimiento'] = cleanData($_POST['regBirth']);
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['fechaInsercion'] = $date;
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['bloqueado'] = false;
        $data[$_POST['regNid']]['ficheros'] = [];
    }
    return;
}

function updateData(&$data) {
    $data[$_POST['updateNid']]['nombre'] = cleanData($_POST['updateName']);
    $data[$_POST['updateNid']]['apellidos'] = cleanData($_POST['updateSurname']);
    $data[$_POST['updateNid']]['correo'] = cleanData($_POST['updateEmail']);
    $data[$_POST['updateNid']]['telefono'] = cleanData($_POST['updatePhone']);
    $data[$_POST['updateNid']]['fechaNacimiento'] = cleanData($_POST['updateBirth']);
    $data[$_POST['updateNid']]['ficheros'][] = cleanData($_FILES['updateFile']['name']);
}

function setBlock(&$data) {
    $data[$_POST['block']]['bloqueado'] = !$data[$_POST['block']]['bloqueado'];
}

?>
```

Puede que haya por ahí algo de código basura (algún print o alguna parte no necesaria), como acabo de resolverlo, preferí subir directamente lo que tenía.

La clave, además de poner el hiddenInputReg en los demás forms o en la tabla, que es donde se cambian los datos, era llamar a la función htmlspecialchars() envolviendo el encodeData() del hiddenInput; en principio, el no tener esa función en el formulario del "updSubmit()" (que está metido en un echo) provocaba que el array $agenda llegase "null" a la función updateData(), seguro por el tema de las comillas, con el htmlspecialchars() me lo solucionó, igualmente lo puse en los demás encodeData() por si acaso, pero imagino que borrando todos a excepción del del echo, debería funcionar sin problema.